# Pass async code to the next screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a game made in Flutter and I want to preload 66 sound bytes which takes about 16 seconds.

```
 _initCardNameSounds()async{
    print(DateTime.now()); //2021-05-16 12:23:38.050985
    for(var x = 0; x < 66; x++){
      cardNameSounds.add(
        await pool.load(
          await rootBundle.load(
            'lib/assets/cardNameAudio/'+(deck[x].split('.png')[0])+'.mp3'
          )
        )
      );
    }
    print(DateTime.now()); //2021-05-16 12:23:50.987699
  }
```

I could add a loading screen before the game while the sounds are loaded ~ but I'd rather start loading the sounds when the app is launched and  by the time the user gets to a game from the menu, the sounds should already be loaded.

My question is ~ how can I pass this async/loading function between multiple screens while it loads?

(Main Menu -> Game mode select -> Player count select -> game)

^Start loading during main menu when app is launched -> should load by the time the game is started.

Comment: Keep the state on the main screen. Instead of navigating into a new screen, change the container of the screen. You can use something like [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) to make it easier.

Comment: BTW, in order to load it faster you can use `Future.wait()` (pass a list of futures) instead of `await`ing in a loop.

Comment: @HTMHell thanks, I think the list of Futures will work for this, I’m going to try it out soon.